# OnTextChanged Odd Issue in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm looking into a very odd issue with our website.  We have a `textbox`, which has an `OnTextChanged event`.  When the event is fired, we auto populate a few add'l textboxes.  This all `works fine in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari`.  IE9 however, has an issue.  `In IE9,` when the event is fired, the page appears to be doing a postback, however after the postback, `ALL fields are blanked out`.  So for example, if I enter in 5 other fields first, then enter data into the textbox with the ontextchanged event, when I exit this textbox, all 6 textbox values are blanked out.

Here's my code:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDAWAgencyName" Width="340px" OnTextChanged="DawLookup" MaxLength="255"></asp:TextBox>

protected void DAWLookup(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Validation.ValidDAW(txtDAW.Text))
    {
        Agency a = Agency.FetchByDAW(Convert.ToInt32(txtDAW.Text));

        if (a != null)
        {
            txtDAWAgencyName.Text = a.agencyName;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.primaryContactId.ToString()))
            {
                MembershipUser mu = Membership.GetUser(a.primaryContactId);
                if (mu != null)
                {
                    GenericProfile gp = GenericProfile.FetchByUserId(a.primaryContactId);
                    if (gp != null)
                    {
                        txtDAWAgencyRep.Text = gp.contactName;
                        txtAgencyRepPhone.Text = gp.contactPhone;
                        txtAgencyRepEmail.Text = mu.UserName;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Here's some details about the issue:

- Works successfully in Chrome, Firefox, & Safari.
- Works successfully in Internet Explorer ONLY in local development
- Does not work in internet explorer on the server.
- There are no double autopostbacks occurring `(only one postback)`

It's the oddest thing.  It works in `all browsers EXCEPT internet explorer 9` on the server (works in local dev environment).  Any idea what may be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your viewstate on page, enable it.

Also try to do Ajax post if you want to save yourself from postback.

I would recommend a UpdatePanel or a jQuery Postback.